# quesrions regarding hurst exponent code in python 3

Tags: python

When I run this code in Python 3，why it shows name “lags” not defined？

```
from numpy import log,sqrt,std,subtract,cumsum,polyfit
def hurst(ts):
    # Create the range of lag values
    lags = range(2, 100)

    # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]  # This line throws the Error

    # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

    # Return the Hurst exponent from the polyfit output
    return poly[0]*2.0
```

Comment: Could you mark the line giving the error?

Comment: The line start with tau,thx

Comment: Weird, when I tried to run it the first errors I got were that `sqrt` and `std` were undefined.

Comment: @vincentchen has you issue been resolved?

Comment: Please post full error message with traceback.

Comment: @machine yearning import them from numpy and try again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didnt import numpy correctly.

Add this to the top of your code:

```
import numpy as np
```

and then change all calls to be:

```
np.polyfit(...)
np.sqrt(...)
```

or if you only want to import the ones you need:

```
from numpy import log, sqrt, std, subtract, cumsum, polyfit
```

Comment: @vincentchen, edit the question and add the traceback.

Comment: Yes,but it still shows name error:'lags' is not defined